# Is there an alternative to the Rails assets pipeline for Django?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, asset-pipeline, requirejs

Using the Rails assets pipeline and a plugin for require.js, I can use CoffeeScript, SASS, files organized however I like and get it all compiled to a single JavaScript and single CSS file for production. Is there a matching setup for use with Django? It needs to support the above, CofeeeScript, SASS, Require.JS with a development mode where files are served individually as well as a production mode where everything gets compiled into single files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I’m using [Django Compressor](http://django_compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) and I’m pretty happy with it. It supports pre-processors so Coffeescript, Sass and so on are supported. Check out the documentation.

EDIT:
Here is my settings for SASS and Coffeescript, in settings.py:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
  'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
  'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)

COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
  ('text/coffeescript', 'coffee --compile --stdio'),
  ('text/x-sass', 'sass {infile} {outfile}'),
  ('text/x-scss', 'sass --scss {infile} {outfile}'),
)
```

Comment: What about getting the requirejs optimizer in there..?

Comment: I created a templatetag for labjs that is compatible with django compressor:https://github.com/ashwoods/django-labjs